# Archive validation failed with errors;

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

---

> Archive validation failed with errors; Unable to validate your
>   application - Could not find a CFBundlePackageType within the
>   info.plist; or the package is missing an info.plist.

---

Hello, 
I'm beginner developer. I just start iOS system. 
I first make the code in Xcode, it's OK about Simulator.
When I'm archiving the app in Xcode, I find this error message like photo. 
So, I have a googling, I see the this website... developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation
But, I don't understand it... Could you tell me some tips?

my property status...

[image]

Comment: You have no bundle name and no executable file? How did that happen??

Comment: see this once may be help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1273/_index.html